# Prove that $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x) dx < +\infty$ then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty}xf(x) =0$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

Suppose that
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x) \,\mathrm dx< +\infty,
$$
the limit of $x\,f(x)$ when $x$ goes to $+\infty$ exists and $\forall x >0$, $f(x) \ge 0$. Can we conclude that
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty}xf(x)=0 ?
$$
I guess that if $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} x f(x) = c \ne 0$, then $U(x)$ will be equivalent to $f(x) = \frac{c}{x}$ when $x$ goes to $+\infty$. Then $f$ will not be integrable. It is a contradiction.
Did I make any mistake?
Thank you for your time

Comment: Big mistake. Why should the limit be $c$? By the way, your title and your question in the text are different.

Comment: @TedShifrin It feels like a "lost in translation" issue but the sentence "the limitation of $x.f(x)$ when $x$ goes to $+\infty$ is available" could easily be a [mis]translation of "the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} x\cdot f(x)$ exists"

Comment: @Gonçalo See my above comment.

Comment: Ah, that addresses one of my points, but not both. :)

Comment: I understand what you mean in the question. But this statement is actually False , if you don't mention that $f$ is continuous. For example take f(x)=0 if $x \in Q$ and 1 if $x \in Q^c$

Comment: @MAHI if $f$ is continuous, does this statement is true?

Comment: @BrianMoehring thank you for your time. Yes, I mean that the limitation of $xf(x)$ when $x$ goes to $+\infty$ exists

Comment: If the limit of $x f(x)$ exists, then your proof is valid. (Why did $f$ become $U$ ?)

Comment: You have more an intuitive argument than a proof, unless you have a good definition of what "equivalent" means and a theorem relating integrability of "equivalent" functions.

Comment: @Gribouillis I am sorry. This is my typo mistake

Comment: @aschepler Yes, that's why I post this question on this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the conjecture is true.

Suppose we have a function $f: \{ x\in \mathbb{R} : x \geq 0\} \to \mathbb{R}$, integrable on every finite interval, with

$$ \lim_{x \to +\infty} x f(x) = L \neq 0 $$

I don't require that $f(x) \geq 0$.

If $L<0$, we can replace $L$ with $-L$ and $f$ with $-f$ to get a case with $L>0$, so assume without loss of generality $L>0$.

Define
$$ I(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\, dt $$

and statements about the improper integral $\int_0^{+\infty} f(x)\, dx$ actually say things about the behavior of $I(x)$ as $x \to +\infty$.

From the first limit, we have that there exists $N>0$ such that $x > N$ implies $|x f(x) - L| < \frac{L}{2}$. This then implies that $x f(x) > \frac{L}{2}$, and $f(x) > \frac{L}{2x}$. So when $x>N$,

$$ \begin{align*}
I(x) &= \int_0^N f(t)\, dt + \int_N^x f(t)\, dt \\
I(x) &\geq \int_0^N f(t)\, dt + \int_N^x \frac{L}{2t}\, dt \\
I(x) &\geq \int_0^N f(t)\, dt + \frac{L}{2t}(\ln x - \ln N)
\end{align*} $$

The first integral is a constant with respect to $x$, so $\lim_{x \to +\infty} I(x) = +\infty$. We also write this conclusion as

$$ \int_0^{+\infty} f(x)\, dx = +\infty $$